# UINavigationController only in first XIB. Apple's EditbleDetailView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

So, In our appDelegate we're all used to creating a uinavigationcontroller outlet and linking it to a uinavigationcontroller in the XIB.

However in subsequent viewcontrollers I can only add uibarbuttonitems programatically by accessing the uinavigationcontroller. Is there a way to add buttons to applications uinavigationcontroller in the other uiviewcontroller's XIBS?

Apple seems to do it in this example: <s>http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/EditableDetailView/index.html</s>

The same question has been asked before in apple's forum but remains unanswered.: <s>http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=8917480#8917480</s>

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried dragging a Navigation Bar to a view in the View Controller's NIB? That will create a Navigation Bar with a Navigation Item under it. You can then create a connection between the navigationItem outlet in your File's Owner (whose class should be set to your View Controller class) and the Navigation Item, which is "under" the Nav Bar.

Comment: Thanks Gordon - I've just tried that and it creates two navigation bars. The one created in my app delegate and the one created in my Xib.. any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you call [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:YourViewControllerObject animated:YES];

then you will get only one but if you are pushing viewController you'll get two.So either hide the root navigationController's NavigationBar or use presentModalViewController.